# Twilio SMS Messaging 2-way

Tags: sms, twilio

I currently have twilio set up for sms marketing. I currently have a problem where I can't reply to the user with the same number.

This is how I have it set up now:

1. Send SMS via twilio
2. IF user replied a webhook is forward to my personal number
3. I have to reply to the user using my personal number
   4.The user is confused as to why I'm not messaging them with the twilio number.

This is how I'd like ot have this set up:

1. Send SMS via twilio.
2. User replies and a hook or number is sent to my personal number.
3. I reply to that number from my person number.
4. Twilio accepts my sms and changes my personal number to twilio number that originally messaged them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

You could use a Twilio Studio flow to [forward the incoming SMS message from your own phone number to a Twilio phone number](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015962887-Forward-Incoming-SMS-Messages-with-Twilio-Studio) and then connect that flow to a Twilio function that [sends that incoming message from your number to the user from the Twilio number](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134287-Forwarding-SMS-messages-to-another-phone-number). (scroll down to the part that mentions Twilio Functions.)

The Twilio function code would look like this:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
  twiml.message(`${event.From}: ${event.Body}`, {
    to: 'user-number'
  });
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```